# Bad file descriptor error in FIO test

Tags: testing, io, benchmarking, microbenchmark

I try to perform a FIO test in a Linux machine with raw disks (no FS). Here is my config file:

```
[global]
direct=1
invalidate=1
ramp_time=30
group_reporting
size=1g
percentile_list=99.999000:99.999990:90.000000:50.000000:99.999900:99.999999:99.000000:99.990000
ioengine=libaio
time_based
runtime=30
rwmixread=72
rw=randrw
filename=/dev/xvdb:/dev/xvdc:/dev/xvdd:/dev/xvde


[readwrite-128k-iodepth-1]
bs=128k
iodepth=1
write_bw_log=128k-iodepth-1.results
write_iops_log=128k-iodepth-1.results


[readwrite-128k-iodepth-2]
bs=128k
iodepth=2
write_bw_log=128k-iodepth-2.results
write_iops_log=128k-iodepth-2.results


[readwrite-128k-iodepth-4]
bs=128k
iodepth=4
write_bw_log=128k-iodepth-4.results
write_iops_log=128k-iodepth-4.results


[readwrite-128k-iodepth-8]
bs=128k
iodepth=8
write_bw_log=128k-iodepth-8.results
write_iops_log=128k-iodepth-8.results


[readwrite-256k-iodepth-1]
bs=256k
iodepth=1
write_bw_log=256-iodepth-8.results
write_iops_log=256-iodepth-8.results


[readwrite-256k-iodepth-2]
bs=256k
iodepth=2
write_bw_log=256-iodepth-8.results
write_iops_log=256-iodepth-8.results


[readwrite-256k-iodepth-4]
bs=256k
iodepth=4
write_bw_log=256-iodepth-8.results
write_iops_log=256-iodepth-8.results


[readwrite-256k-iodepth-8]
bs=256k
iodepth=8
write_bw_log=256-iodepth-8.results
write_iops_log=256-iodepth-8.results
```

when I run this config like:

```
fio ./fio.cfg  --output=fio.out
```

I receive:

```
file:filesetup.c:288, func=blockdev_size, error=Bad file descriptor
```

So I guess it's a tiny detail I skip but it's first time I run FIO test so not sure what it could be. So any comment would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

as I said, very tiny detail skipped. I replaced size=1g with size=1G and it worked.

Comment: Curious. The integer suffix is not supposed to case sensitive according to the HOWTO...